# selected checkbox in wpf

Tags: wpf, checkbox

am having a set of checkbox in a stackpanel,
i want to get the selected checkbox in my code..

how i can get those selected checkbox in a stackpanel

Comment: Not sure what your scenario is, but if these checkboxes represent data points (e.g. which purchase orders are approved) rather than being controls with a specific behavioural purpose, it's easier and more idiomatic in WPF to use a databound ItemsControl or ListBox, with the CheckBox as part of its DataTemplate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the children of the stackpanel.

```
IEnumerable<CheckBox> selectedBoxes =
    from checkbox in this.stackPanel1.Children.OfType<CheckBox>()
    where checkbox.IsChecked.Value
    select checkbox;

foreach (CheckBox box in selectedBoxes)
{
    // do something 
}
```

Same query in lambda form

```
IEnumerable<CheckBox> selectedBoxes =
    this.stackPanel1.Children.OfType<CheckBox>()
    .Where(cb => cb.IsChecked.Value);
```

Comment: You can make this easier with the OfType operator: `from cb in stackPanel1.Children.OfType<CheckBox>() where cb.IsChecked.Value select cb`.  Saves the test in the `where` clause and the repeated casts.

Comment: hai itowlson,
i can t understand wat you saying. can u tell me in some more detailed...